# Nginx Php Image with php code upload attack

Tags: php, nginx

My web site use nginx + php-fpm.I have already set `fix_pathinfo = 0`  in php.ini .

But I found in my site's upload folder there is a php script `0.php` and a .gif file contained some php code about '0.php' in it.

When I try to reproduce this bug issue with open link `http://example.com/folder/attack.gif/1.php`,it returned `404`.

How can I prevent this kind of attack?

Comment: Posti your uploading code.

Comment: I can not change the php code.

Comment: Did the provided solution help?

Comment: No.I can not reproduce this bug.